# how to compare line series compare in birt report

Tags: birt

i am doing a report with check-box for instance am having name like country,state as check box so i have click country over it have
       to produce a this year(2013) and last(2012) sale value .by line chart
      it is like by clicking of check box it have to compare by line series?

how to achieve this ?

Comment: is there any idea about this...?

Comment: The question is either not clear, or is so basic it indicates you don't know how to use parameters.